# How do I set the UEFI memory map for a MacBook with Bad RAM?

Tags: ram, uefi

I'm trying to fix a friends MacBook Air. We detected bad / corrupt RAM with memtest, but since RAM can't be replaced I was thinking it must be possible to alter the memory map to avoid certain RAM sections like the Linux kernel parameter memmap used to do in older (not UEFI) machines. Some one kindly pointed me towards Clover, but I have been reading the docs and have not found any way to alter the memory map.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution of the original problem is to replace the faulty RAM module, it can be done by any skilled repairman with BGA rework station.

As for the solution mentioned: you can develop a very simple UEFI application that will use [gBS->AllocatePages](http://wiki.phoenix.com/wiki/index.php/EFI_BOOT_SERVICES#AllocatePages.28.29) to allocate the faulty memory block completelly as [EfiUnusableMemory](http://www.bluestop.org/edk2/docs/trunk/_uefi_multi_phase_8h.html#a0e2cdd0290e753cca604d3977cbe8bb9), so it will automatically be added to UEFI memory map and then call the original Apple's boot.efi loader.